# When will developer.ubuntu.com review apps again?

Tags: software-center

I submitted my first app into Ubuntu Software Center, but I get this error:
[image]

What does that error mean? Will my game get reviewed, or do I need to do something more?

**EDIT:**

Does anyone know when the site will be reviewing apps again?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going out on a limb here.

Its just what the message says.  There will be a new way of submitting apps, that is being worked on, and will be implemented once all the testing is done.

I don't think that your app will be reviewed at this time, and in the mean time, you can use a ppa to market your product, either as a free app or paid.

If I have to guess, I will have to say soon after Ubuntu 13.10 comes out.

Comment: Alright thanks, do you know when the new way of submitting apps will be working?

Comment: I don't at this time, but I'll drop you a note here once I find out.

Comment: @Jeggy Take a look [Here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/).

Comment: Thanks Mitch, but how do i find out what I'm missing? Cause i don't think i have missed anything :/  as my app is still in draft mode :http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/application-states/

Comment: @Jeggy See if [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppDevUploadProcess) gives you any new info.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have three options here:

- Submit your app to debian and get it backported to the current ubuntu.
- Wait for the new app submission process(no info available on how long for) this will require changing your app to use the new Click package format, which doesn't support non ubuntu SDK dependencies.
- Use a PPA